# Using underscore synatx in URI with implicit controller in laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I know this:

If your controller action contains multiple words, you may access the action using "**dash**" syntax in the URI. For example, the following controller action on our UserController would respond to the `users/admin-profile` URI:

```
public function getAdminProfile() {}
```

Want to the know about:

If i want to use "**underscore**" synatx in the URI. Is it possible with implicit controllers.

Like want to use `user/admin_profile` in the URI. What would controller look like?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

In your `routes.php` file add

- `Route::get('user/admin_profile', 'UserController@getAdminProfile');`

Comment: But this is not implicit controller, here take a look https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/controllers#implicit-controllers